# Transition between two forms using show and hide does not behave as I expect

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms. The first is the parent and contains a reference to the second and a button:

```
public class Form1:Form {

       private Form2 frm2;
       private Button btnShow;
...

}
```

When I press the button frm2 must be shown (visible and in front of all other windows) and Form1 must hide.

When I press the closebox of frm2, frm2 must hide and Form1 must be shown (reverse).

I used the click event of btnShow to register a handle that all it does is:

```
    private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        frm2.Show(this);
    }
```

and in the FormClosing event of frm2:

```
    private void byebye(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Hide();
            Owner.Show();
        }
    }
```

My codes works for 90% of the time but sometimes (i cannot specify when) the shown form
is not brought to front or loses focus (I am not sure about that i think the first).

What I am doing wrong. I've tried alternating the order of Show and Hide and using of a new reference instead of Owner, I also used Activate,BringToFront, Focus but with no success...

Comment: If you don't mind your parent form being visible in the background, you could use ShowDialog instead, that's the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Hide();
    Owner.Show();
```

You are doing this the wrong way around.  For a split second, there's no single window left in your application that can receive the focus.  The Windows window manager is forced to find another window to give the focus to.  Which will be the window of another application.  With good odds that this is a large enough window to cover your own.  Your Show() call will thus make your window visible again, but now underneath that window that got moved into the foreground.  This doesn't always happen btw, the window manager appears to use a small timeout.  The longer the owner has been hidden, the greater the odds that its code has been swapped out and that showing it takes more time, thus tripping the timeout.

The workaround is simple, just swap the two statements so you'll always have window that can be focused.  Fix:

```
    Owner.Show();
    Hide();
```

Comment: I think that did the trick. The thing is I am not sure cause the problem is pretty rare. I ll test it a little more and then I ll accept this as the correct anwser.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply:

```
{
    Form2 fm = new Form2();
    this.Visible = false;
    fm.ShowDialog();
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

Works for me.

Comment: This approach suffers from the *exact* same problem.